# why the operation “>>1” do not mean "/2" with int data in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I will input vector: {6501,6828,6963,7036,7422,7674,8146,8468,8704,8717,9170,9359,9719,9895,9896,9913,9962,154,293,334,492,1323,1479,1539,1727,1870,1943,2383,2392,2996,3282,3812,3903,4465,4605,4665,4772,4828,5142,5437,5448,5668,5706,5725,6300,6335 };

If i compute the "Mid" with the code in below function and the result is 154, but when I compute the "Mid" with "Mid = Left + (Right-Left)>>1" and the result will be 1479.
I don't understand what happened? Why these two ways output the different result?

The function is:

```
    int minNumberInRotateArray(vector<int> rotateArray) {
        if (!rotateArray.size()) return 0;
        int Left = 0, Right = rotateArray.size() - 1;
        int Mid = Left + (Right - Left)/2;
        while (Left < Right)
        {
            if (rotateArray[Left] < rotateArray[Mid]) Left = Mid;
            else if (rotateArray[Right] > rotateArray[Mid]) Right = Mid;
            else return rotateArray[Right];
            Mid = Left + (Right - Left)/2;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What result is correct?

Comment: Did you try `Mid = Left + ((Right-Left)>>1)`? I'm afraid that's a matter of operator precedence.

Comment: have you tried: `(-1 >> 10)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator >> has a lower precedence value than +.

This means that `a + (b - c) >> d` is actually interpreted as `(a + (b - c)) >> d` and not `a + ((b - c) >> 1)` as you would expect.

You can look at the operator precedence level table in here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence.

I suggest using /, since good compilers will optimize divisions by two using shifts anyway, and it's clearer what you are trying to do.
Alternatively, you can consider using parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Your issues is with operator precedence. You should use `Left + ((Right - Left) >> 1)`. But if you want to know when `>> 1` is different from `/2`, think about `-1`:

- `-1 / 2 == 0`
- `-1 >> 1 == -1`

The fact that they are different means that compilers do not simply optimize `/ 2` to `>> 1`. This is what GCC generates for division:

```
mov    %edi,%eax
shr    $0x1f,%eax
add    %edi,%eax
sar    %eax
```

And shifting generates:

```
sar    %eax
```